# In Office 2013, how to set document view mode for each file?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

Let's say we have two files 00.docx viewed under `Print Layout` mode and 11.docx `Web Layout` mode.

In Word 2013, when I change the view mode of one file, that mode will be used for other files which I don't want to.

Since each file has the best layout of its own, I need ways to save this view mode of one docx file.

I can do this in Word 2010 but cannot with Word 2013.

Please support.

Comment: Does this also happen when the Word files are in different folders ?

Comment: Yes it does. Containing folders do not matter here.